# Regular Express - match all char but pattern at the end of line

Tags: regex

I'm trying to put together a regular expression but I seem to be missing the target.  I've used simple regular expressions before, but the negations always trip me up.

I need to match an entire string except for any portion of the string that ends with and characters in between two square brackets [  ]

Example:

```
Hello, World! [strip this]
```

It should match:

```
Hello, World!
```

Anything in between the open/close square brackets including the square brackets should be stripped.  However, I only want to match the last set.

So the following example,

```
Hello, [cold] World! [strip this]
```

Should leave,

```
Hello, [cold] World!
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a negation here. Just anchor your regex at the end: replace `\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*$` with nothing:

```
fge@erwin ~ $ perl -ne 's,\s*\[[^\]]+\]\s*$,,; print "Result: -->$_<--\n"'
Hello, World! [strip this]
Result: -->Hello, World!<--
Hello, [cold] World! [strip this]
Result: -->Hello, [cold] World!<--
fge@erwin ~ $
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(.*)(\s*\[.*\])
```

The part you want will be in capture group 1. See it in action here: http://rubular.com/r/P9xczF2AVI

Comment: Why capture all the input when all you need to capture is at the end?

Comment: He doesn't want the end, he wants the beginning. And yes, you could take away the parentheses around the second group, I just added them in to better illustrate the two pieces being captured.

Comment: No, you want to capture the end to remove it. Hence, no need to match the beginning! In fact, no need to have a capture at all here.